# Android USB HID claiming and releasing interface around bulktranfer necessary?

Tags: android, usb, hid

I'm now communicating from an Android USB HID host to a device. I have one read and one write endpoint in the same interface. On the Android host I do

```
UsbInterface        Intf       = _usbDevice.getInterface(0);
UsbEndpoint         Ep         = Intf.getEndpoint(1);
UsbDeviceConnection Connection = _usbManager.openDevice(_usbDevice);

Connection.claimInterface(Intf, true);

Connection.bulkTransfer(Ep, data, data.length, 0);

Connection.releaseInterface(Intf);
Connection.close();
```

So for writing I do: claim the interface -> transfer -> release interface -> close

For reading I do the same in another thread.

Do I need to open, claim, release and close the interface every time when I do a read or write on one of the two endpoints (both endpoints in the same interface)? Or can I open, claim, release and close ones at the start and end of my program and during the programs lifetime read and write to the endpoints without claiming and releasing every time around a bulktransfer?

Answer (score 2):

In my case (LG G4, Android 5.*) I have defined private statics of all needed objects (UsbDeviceConnection, UsbEndpoint, UsbInterface, etc).

I'm doing the entire progress Android has written on their [usb host page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html).

After the initialization progress I'm only using [queue()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbRequest.html#queue%28java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20int%29) and requestWait() at the endpoints to communicate with the initialized device until the user releases the device.

Therefore I don't think you need to do always your posted chain: claim the interface -> transfer -> release interface -> close ...